# Creating a Python list or dictionary with a set number of rows, but variable number of columns per row

Tags: python, list, numpy

I'm working with images and want to create a list of lists of arrays. For example, a list with 5 rows, where each row has a variable number of images (3x200x100) stored in them ranging from 2 images to 10 images.

I've ruled out numpy and concatenation since they need the matrix to be uniform. I've tried appending one list to another, but that just gives me a long row of them when what I want is another row to be added after the prior row.

I was thinking that either a list or a dictionary would be the way to go since what I'm using to populate my list of lists is a dictionary, but I'm unable to figure out how to structure the lists so that it's correct to my above specifications instead of just a super long list. Is there any way for me to initialize a list so that only the row number gets specified and I can dynamically change the column number per row? If not, is there a different data structure I should be looking at?

Comment: If you create a list where each element is a list, you get a list of lists, and each sublist can have its own size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
row1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
row2 = [1,2,3]

matrix = [row1, row2]

row3 = [1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9]
matrix.append(row3)
```

Comment: Since it isn't possible to append to a list that hasn't been initialized, is there any way of not specifying what goes in "matrix"?

Comment: @user6664585 Just initialize it to an empty list. `matrix = []`